# How to get the checkbox value selected from excel sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working on a task related to reading an excel which contains radio buttons and checkbox using Java, I have tried a lot but can't move further on this, when I am trying to read the data of cell containing Checkbox it is returning a null value.

[image]

Can someone please help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Controls are not contained in the cells but hovers in the drawing layer over the sheet as shapes and only are anchored to the cells. So the cell may be null (because of no content in it) although a shape hovers over it and is anchored to it.

Moreover there are two different kinds of controls possible. There are form controls and `ActiveX` controls. The states of `ActiveX` controls are stored in binary code parts `activeX1.bin` and thus  getting the state of them is very hard.

In earlier `Excel` versions (2007 for example) the anchor informations of all controls are stored in `/xl/drawings/vmlDrawing1.vml` only. Later versions are storing them in default drawing and within

```
<controls>
 <mc:AlternateContent>
  ...
 </mc:AlternateContent>
</controls>
```

parts in the sheet `XML` too. Fortunately there is also `/xl/drawings/vmlDrawing1.vml` for backwards compatibility.

The following code does parsing the  `/xl/drawings/vmlDrawing1.vml` to get the control which is possible anchored to a cell. If found, it gets this control and if this control is a form control and **not** a `ActiveX` control, then it also can get it's state. For `ActiveX` controls it gets only the information, that a "Pict" is anchored to this cell.

Excel:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

class ReadExcelXSSFControls {

 public ReadExcelXSSFControls() throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook wb  = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelWithControls.xlsx"));

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
    if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
     System.out.print(cell + "\t");
    } else {
     if (c == 0) {
      System.out.print(cell + "\t");
     } else if (c == 1) {
      if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(c);
      Control contol = getControlAt((XSSFCell)cell);
      System.out.print(contol);     
     }
    }
   }
   System.out.println();
  }

  wb.close();
 }

 private Control getControlAt(XSSFCell cell) throws Exception {
  XSSFSheet sheet = cell.getSheet();
  Row row =  cell.getRow();
  int r = row.getRowNum();
  int c = cell.getColumnIndex();

  int drheight = (int)Math.round(sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints() * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI);
  int rheight = (int)Math.round(row.getHeightInPoints() * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI);
  row = null;
  if(r > 0) row = sheet.getRow(r-1);
  int rheightbefore = (row!=null)?(int)Math.round(row.getHeightInPoints() * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI):drheight;
  row = sheet.getRow(r+1);
  int rheightafter = (row!=null)?(int)Math.round(row.getHeightInPoints() * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI):drheight;

  String name = null;
  String objectType = null;
  String checked = null;

  XmlCursor xmlcursor = null;
  if (sheet.getCTWorksheet().getLegacyDrawing() != null) {
   String legacyDrawingId = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getLegacyDrawing().getId();
   POIXMLDocumentPart part = sheet.getRelationById(legacyDrawingId);
   XmlObject xmlDrawing = XmlObject.Factory.parse(part.getPackagePart().getInputStream());
   xmlcursor = xmlDrawing.newCursor();
   QName qnameClientData = new QName("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel", "ClientData", "x");
   QName qnameAnchor = new QName("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel", "Anchor", "x");
   boolean controlFound = false;
   while (xmlcursor.hasNextToken()) {
    XmlCursor.TokenType tokentype = xmlcursor.toNextToken();
    if (tokentype.isStart()) {
     if (qnameClientData.equals(xmlcursor.getName())) {
      controlFound = true;
      XmlObject clientdata = xmlcursor.getObject();
      XmlObject[] xmlchecked = clientdata.selectPath("declare namespace x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' x:Checked");
      if (xmlchecked.length > 0) {
       checked = "Checked";
      } else {
       checked = "Not checked";
      }
      while (xmlcursor.hasNextToken()) {
       tokentype = xmlcursor.toNextToken(); 
       if (tokentype.isAttr()) {
        if (new QName("ObjectType").equals(xmlcursor.getName())) {
         objectType = xmlcursor.getTextValue();
         name = objectType + " in row " + (r+1);
        } 
       } else {
        break;
       }
      }
     } else if (qnameAnchor.equals(xmlcursor.getName()) && controlFound) {
      controlFound = false;
      String anchorContent = xmlcursor.getTextValue().trim();
      String[] anchorparts = anchorContent.split(",");
      int fromCol = Integer.parseInt(anchorparts[0].trim());
      int fromColDx = Integer.parseInt(anchorparts[1].trim());
      int fromRow = Integer.parseInt(anchorparts[2].trim());
      int fromRowDy = Integer.parseInt(anchorparts[3].trim());
      int toCol = Integer.parseInt(anchorparts[4].trim());
      int toColDx = Integer.parseInt(anchorparts[5].trim());
      int toRow = Integer.parseInt(anchorparts[6].trim());
      int toRowDy = Integer.parseInt(anchorparts[7].trim());

      if (fromCol == c /*needs only starting into the column*/
       && (fromRow == r || (fromRow == r-1 && fromRowDy > rheightbefore/2f)) 
       && (toRow == r || (toRow == r+1 && toRowDy < rheightafter/2f))) {
//System.out.print(fromCol + ":" +fromColDx + ":" + fromRow + ":" + fromRowDy + ":" + toCol + ":" + toColDx + ":" + toRow + ":" + toRowDy);
       break;
      }
     } 
    } 
   }
  }

  if (xmlcursor!=null && xmlcursor.hasNextToken()) 
   return new Control(name, objectType, checked, r, c);

  return new Control("Not found", "unknown", "undefined", r, c); 
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  ReadExcelXSSFControls o = new ReadExcelXSSFControls();
 }

 private class Control {
  private String name;
  private String objectType;
  private String checked;
  private int row;
  private int col;
  public Control(String name, String objectType, String checked, int row, int col) {
   this.name = name;
   this.objectType = objectType;
   this.checked = checked;
   this.row = row;
   this.col= col;
  }
  public String getName() {
   return this.name;
  }
  public String getObjectType() {
   return this.objectType;
  }
  public String getChecked() {
   return this.checked;
  }
  public int getRow() {
   return this.row;
  }
  public int getCol() {
   return this.col;
  }
  public String toString() {
   return this.name + ":r/c:" +row+ "/" + col + ":" + this.checked;
  }
 }
}
```

Result:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-3.17$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* ReadExcelXSSFControls 
Product  Status 
a        Checkbox in row 2:r/c:1/1:Checked
b        Not found:r/c:2/1:undefined
c        Checkbox in row 4:r/c:3/1:Not checked
d        Checkbox in row 5:r/c:4/1:Checked
e        Radio in row 6:r/c:5/1:Checked
f        Not found:r/c:6/1:undefined
g        Not found:r/c:7/1:undefined
e        Checkbox in row 9:r/c:8/1:Checked
f        Not found:r/c:9/1:undefined
h        Radio in row 11:r/c:10/1:Not checked
ActiveX  Pict in row 14:r/c:13/1:Not checked
```

---

Since Apache POI version 5 it is:

```
...
//import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
...
```

Comment: HI Axel, Thanks for the code. But am facing a problem. All the checkboxes are identified, but still for some of the checkboxes, the checked value is not properly returned. Am trying to solve this, but your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Prabahar: As said ActiveX controls cannot be parsed using my code. But if your controls are form controls and it does not work then my suspicion is that the controls were not created and/or manipulated using `Excel` but using any third part software which has not properly updated `/xl/drawings/vmlDrawing1.vml`.

Comment: Axel: It was a mistake in the Document and i have fixed it. now it all works fine. Great!!  I have another query, when i try to use XLS for this code not able to proceed through. getRelations method is not available. Is this code for XLS too? is there any other way i can achieve checkbox reading in XLS?

Comment: @Prabahar: This code is for `XSSF` (Office Open XML file format, `*.xlsx`) only. And no, I do not know how to read form controls from `HSSF`(binary BIFF file format, `*.xls`). HSSF stands for **H**orrible **S**pread**S**heet **F**ormat and this name is true.