# Java: Read excel Form control values in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Can anybody please let me know how to read the values of Excel form controls (radio button, checkbox, drop-down etc) in Java?

I tried using Apache POI, but I couldn't find a way to read the value of radio buttons or checkbox.

I know that I can link the form control with a particular cell in excel, and when the value of form control changes, read the data from that cell. But, instead of following this approach, I am looking for a way to directly read the value of form control.

I searched google but couldn't find anything useful. So can anybody please help me here?

I do not have any limitation of using any API's. So please let me know if this can be done in Java or not.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960620/how-to-get-the-checkbox-value-selected-from-excel-sheet-apache-poi/48972176#48972176

Comment: @AxelRichter... Thanks for passing the link. Will go through it and see if I can understand it.