# POI Read XLS /XLSX, checkbox value java

Tags: java, excel, checkbox, apache-poi

I have an Excel sheet which contains checkboxes as part of it data.  I need to get the checked value of the checkboxes individually. Not able to find a clear help in internet.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960620/how-to-get-the-checkbox-value-selected-from-excel-sheet-apache-poi

Comment: HI, Thanks for the link. It works to an extent. it identifies all the checkboxes in the sheet. But the checked value is not returning properly for all checkboxes. For few it works and others it not picking up. Need help.

Comment: Fixed it.  used the code with some tweaks.